# Can't access tfs server using vs2010, 404 error returns

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am using vs2010 and tfs2010 for my work. I can't access the server while my colleagues can. When I tried to access the server which is http://mytfs:8080/, it responses: balbla and 3 possible reasons and "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

I checked my client settings and compare with my colleagues, nothing is different. No tfs proxy, only default IE proxy setting. No path is is set. No stored credentials in my system account management (Windows XP), same dns/host setting.

Besides, I can telnet the server with port 8080 using command window. I can also browse the http://mytfs:8090/ using my domain account in my web browser. Moreover, the admin tells me that due to the tfs server's log, it has received my post request and responsed 200 OK.
I tried change mytfs to ip address but still got 404 response.

I googled the problem and found it much like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978148) , but the patch cannot be installed(is says this update does not appply or blocked by another condition). Can someone help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you a remote worker? If not, this sounds like you should be speaking with your local IT administrator.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I find the problem. It is because the tfs use cache to connect to an old server for NTLM authrization, which is already shut down.

I use fiddler to monitor what happens when connect to the tfs server. It first post data to http://**mytfs**:8080/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/LocationService.asmx and got a 401 response, and go to http://**oldtfs**:8080/Services/v1.0/GroupSecurityService.asmx, which responses 502, then http://**mytfs**:8080/TeamFoundation/Administration/v3.0/LocationService.asmx responses 404 (Which is an odd reponse).

So there must be some config which keeps the old server's authorize information. After checking host files and register entires. I think it may be the tfs client which caches the authorize url. So I removed C:\Documents and Settings\myaccount\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache, restart vs2010, it can successfully connect.

Hope this can help someone with the same problem.

Comment: Great that you found the problem. Can you mark your post as the answer?

Comment: Here are instructions for clearing the cache on a Windows 7 client accessing either TFS 2010 or TFS 2012: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19122717/1943

Answer (score 4):

A default installation of TFS 2010 will install to a virtual directory of `/tfs/`. Without specifying that in your connection path, the server will return a `404` error.

Try and connect to: `http://mytfs:8080/tfs/`

Comment: hi Grant, this is not the tfs path problem, we just use the root directory. Even if I add tfs to the path input(which is default), a 404 is still returned.