# Visual Studio 2012 keeps losing connection with TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm working with Visual Studio 2012 and when I wanted to check in my pending changes (on TFS 2010), all of sudden VS loses its connection with TFS and says (on the Team Explorer window): "HTTP Code 404: not found". The option to check in (or to shelve) is disabled. When I try to refresh the source control explorer window, it briefly shows my folders, but then closes it again (saying it was disconnected with TFS). The funny thing is that I still can get the latest version from TFS and even see my pending changes, but when I try to check these in or shelve my pending changes, it loses the connection.

I tried looking for an answer on Google, but the only answer I found was clearing the TFS cache at C:\Users\\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache or starting up VS with the VS command prompt with the command "devenv /ResetSkipPkgs".

I'm clueless. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Clearing the TFS cache per your instructions worked for me. Good luck!

Comment: How annoying is this when bouncing between numerous projects daily that live in TFS 2010 and 2012. To clear the cache and have it work, you have to close/open VS.  Huge pain when this happens multiples times a day.  I have found no real solution.  But, it does work, then eventually breaks again.

Comment: There might be a lot of things causing it. Try following this article:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2008/06/26/troubleshooting-connections-to-tfs.aspx

Comment: This continues with VS 2013. Microsoft knows how to irk its users shoot itself in its foot damn too well!

Answer (score 18):

On a Windows 7 client running against TFS 2010, clear the contents of the following folder:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache
```

On a Windows 7 client running against TFS 2012, clear the contents of the following folder:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0\Cache
```

On a Windows 7 client running against TFS 2013, clear the contents of the following folder:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache
```