# Visual Studio loses connection to TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfs-2015, team-explorer

I use Visual Studio 2015 and connect throught a VPN to a TFS 2015.
It happens that the VPN disconnects, when it happens VS loses the connection to TFS. When the VPN reconnect, I can't connect back to TFS, I get an error: "The remote name could not be resolved". The only way to reconnect is to close VS and relaunch it.

I guess it's not that bad since it does not happens often.

But recently, the error started to happen regularly, even when there is no drop in the connection. I get the same error as before and I can't "just" reconnect to TFS, I need to restart VS.

Following advices from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15920440/visual-studio-2012-keeps-losing-connection-with-tfs-2010), I cleared my cache in this directory:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache
```

I also tried to install Power Tools for TFS 2015 to launch the "Best Practices Analyzer Tool" only to find out [it was no longer supported](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power) in this version.

I would continue to blame the VPN or some other network micro cuts, but my colleagues on the same network don't have these issues.

Any idea of the cause of this issue or a way to make VS more resilient ?

What I don't get is why the reconnect fails, and why it works only when I restart VS. If I could just reconnect to TFS without restarting, it would already be a major plus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this issue only occurs on your machine, but your colleagues on the same network works perfect. Most likely related to your VS. To narrow down if the issue  related to your personal account, try to use your account on colleagues' computer for test.

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache` will only clear the TFS cache , you need to also clear VS cache typical location for 64 bit: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE` Source Link: [If you have problems with TFS or Visual Studio flush the user cache … or not?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) Also **clear IE cache** on your dev machine.

If you don't mind, you could also try to reinstall your VS.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try first resetting all the cache. I'd prefer not to reinstall but if this doesn't work I'll do it...

Comment: My issues seems to have vanished since clearing all the cache, thanks !

Comment: Well, the problems are back, I guess clearing the cache fix is only temporary. I'll try reinstalling Visual Studio if I find the time...

Comment: Hi @NicolasC Did you figured out this issue after reinstalled Visual Studio?

Comment: Hi @Patrick-MSFT, thanks for asking how it goes. I don't really know what happened but the issues have disappeared again and I didn't do anything. I didn't find the time to reinstall Visual Studio, I didn't clear the cache either. My colleagues don't use the VPN anymore so I can't be sure. I guess I will blame the VPN after all !

Comment: Glad to hear the issue fixed. Sounds like your network environment is not so stable due to the VPN.  Next time if you still occurs this issue, you could also [catch VS log](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx) to analysis the issue. If it helps, could you mark  it as an answer.